# apply function in a character dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 GID7173723 GID4878677 GID88208 GID346403 GID268825 GID7399578
1           A          A        A         A         G          A
2           T          T        T         T         C          T
3           G          G        G         G         G          G
4           A          A        A         A         A          A
5           G          G        G         G         G          G
6           G          G        G         G         G          G
7           A          A        A         A         A          A
8           G          G        G         G         G          G
9           A          A        A         A         A          A
10          A          A        A         A         A          A
```

However, when I use the apply function to get the sum of all 'A' by row divided by the number of columns in the dataframe, I get the total sum of A's instead of getting row sums.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
myfun <- function(x){
 out <-  sum(x=='A')/ncol(x)
 return(out)
}
apply(df,MARGIN = 1,FUN=myfun)
```

I cannot figure out why the apply function gives me the total sum of A and not by row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df1=="A")/ncol(df1)
```

Or use `rowMeans

```
rowMeans(df1 == "A")
```

---

With `apply`, the `ncol` doesn't apply as it is a `vector`, so we need `length(x)`

```
myfun <- function(x){
  sum(x=='A')/length(x)
  #or
  # mean(x == "A")

 }
```

Comment: thanks I figured that out , but I really would like to stick to apply to solve it.

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  Updated the solution.  It will be slow with `apply`

Comment: OP why do you want to stick to apply ?

Comment: because apply is a vectorised form and would be much faster than a for loop right ?

Comment: and could you guys explain me why sum does not 'obey' the apply margin and and gives me the total sum instead ?

Comment: that works , thanks. however if I write is.vector(length(df)) R tells me TRUE. so what is length(df) ?

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  `length(df)` is also the number of columns and it returns a single number.  What i meant with `x` is that it is a `vector` as it is looping through each row in `apply`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with `apply()`**

```
apply(df, 1,FUN=function(rowVec) table(rowVec)['A'])
```

`table()` gives counts of each of the bases - you select 'A' out of them.